# how to reset to commit while discarding untracked files?

Tags: git

I'd like to reset to a commit and, if there's any new file in my working directory, it should be deleted.

That was the behavior I've expected from `git reset --hard [<commit>]` but it simply ignores new files while reverting changes on modified files to how it was.

Consider the following example, where I do the following:

- delete file `main.c`
- commit this change
- create file `main.c`
- revert to previous commit

And expected `main.c` to no longer exist.

```
$:~/dev/gittests$ ls
main.c
$:~/dev/gittests$ rm main.c
$:~/dev/gittests$ git add *
fatal: pathspec '*' não encontrou nenhum arquivo
$:~/dev/gittests$ git status
No ramo master
Mudanças a serem submetidas:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    main.c

$:~/dev/gittests$ git commit -m "deleted main"
[master 84de2d3] deleted main
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 main.c
$:~/dev/gittests$ ls
$:~/dev/gittests$ touch main.c
$:~/dev/gittests$ ls
main.c
$:~/dev/gittests$ git status
No ramo master
Arquivos não monitorados:
  (utilize "git add <arquivo>..." para incluir o que será submetido)

    main.c

nada adicionado ao envio mas arquivos não registrados estão presentes (use "git add" to registrar)
$:~/dev/gittests$ git log
commit 84de2d30505cb6526a2f28918c8b37e4c086db59 (HEAD -> master)
Author: ******
Date:   Wed May 15 01:34:27 2019 -0300

    deleted main

commit 04382fc20f2fe6dc36ce4443c97f83b786f87781
Author: *****
Date:   Wed May 15 01:14:02 2019 -0300

    initial commit
$:~/dev/gittests$ git reset --hard 84de2d
HEAD is now at 84de2d3 deleted main
$:~/dev/gittests$ ls
main.c
```

Comment: Take a look at `git clean`: https://koukia.ca/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-branch-571c6ce9b6b1

Comment: That's just what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+untracked+files

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate because I might not want to go back to the previous commit, even though that's the usual case.